# photo not storing onto the database. php [undefined Index]

Tags: php, ajax

I have form like this:

```
<form class="wrefresh" action="Code Files/Accused.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div class="row-form">
    <div class="span3" style="margin-top: 06px">Picture:</div>

     <div id="photo_settings2" style="margin-left:11px;">
         <img id="Picture2" src="../../img/User No-Frame.png"/>       
     </div>

    <div id='Upload_Panel'>
       <input name="file" type='file' id='file_browse' onchange="readURL(this,'Picture2')"    style="cursor: pointer;"/>
    </div>
</div> 

<button type="submit" class="a-btn2"style="cursor: pointer; background-color:#5C635F; color:white; font-family:'Candara'; margin-top:-47px; margin-left:192px; height:37px;"><big>Submit</big></button>

</form>
```

I have a php code in Accused.php:

```
$Mother_Language           =         $_POST['mlang'];
$Other_Languages           =         $_POST['olang'];
$Complexion                =         $_POST['comp'];
$Previous_Thug_Record      =         $_POST['precord'];
$Religion                  =         $_POST['religion'];
$Type_of_Accused           =         $_POST['taccused'];              
$City                      =         $_POST['city'];
$Country                   =         $_POST['country'];
$Nationality               =         $_POST['nationality'];
$ID_Mark                   =         $_POST['idmark'];
$Hair_Color                =         $_POST['haircolor'];
$Occupation                =         $_POST['occupation'];
$Academic_Info             =         $_POST['ainfo'];
$Alias                     =         $_POST['alias'];
$Caste                     =         $_POST['caste'];
$Sect                      =         $_POST['sect'];
$Remarks                   =         $_POST['remarks'];

    $photo    =   $_POST['file'];   // giving error : undefined index/ getting nothing from the form.
```

### my ajax function is:

```
<script>
var frm = $('.wrefresh');

frm.submit(function (ev)
{

    ev.preventDefault();

    var postdate = $(this).serialize();
    var path = $(this).attr("action");
    var mehtodtype = $(this).attr("method").toUpperCase();

    $(".loadingimg").show();

    $.ajax
    ({
        type: mehtodtype,
        url: path,
        data: postdate,
        success: function(data) 
        {
            // Get Form Data.
            $("#FIRtable").html(data);
            $("#Accusedtable").html(data);

            // Clear fields data.
            $('form :input[type=text], textarea').attr('value', '');

            // show hide icons when click on submit.
            $(".loadingimg").delay(1000).fadeOut();
            setTimeout(function()
            {
                $(".okicon").fadeIn('slow');
                $(".okicon").delay(2800).fadeOut();
            }, 1800);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

I think my error is because of the ajax function i am using. I am getting every thing working except `$photo = $_POST['file'];` this  // giving error : `undefined index`. help  would be appreciated.

Comment: you want the `$_FILES` array for the details of the file

Comment: RTFM: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php   file uploads are handled via `$_FILES`, not `$_POST`.

Comment: i used $_FILES but its not working too please help me. same error showing undefined index

Comment: `print_r($_FILES);` will show you the values you have to work with

Comment: this showing: Array ( )

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Uploading files through AJAX is a lot more complex than just referencing the `$_FILES` array.  You'll need something like this to handle the file upload:

```
function upload_file() {
    var formData = new FormData( document.getElementById( "form-uploader" ));

    $.ajax( {
        url         : "Code Files/Accused.php",
        type        : "post",
        xhr         : function() {
            my_xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            if( my_xhr.upload ) {
                my_xhr.upload.addEventListener( "progress", handler_progress, false );
            }

            return my_xhr;
        },

        beforeSend  : handler_before_send,
        success     : handler_complete,
        error       : handler_error,
        data        : formData,
        contentType : false,
        processData : false
    } );
}
```

The primary difference between this and your code is that it employes the JavaScript `FormData` object, which is required to upload files with AJAX.

And then a variety of supporting functions that will be called when the upload starts, what its progress is, if there are any errors, and when it completes:

```
function handler_progress( e ) {
    if( e.lengthComputable ) {
        $( "progress" ).attr( {value:e.loaded, max:e.total} );
    }
}

function handler_before_send( e ) {
    var progress = $( "<progress></progress>" ).attr( "id", "progress-bar" );
    $( "#form-uploader" ).append( progress );
}

function handler_error( e ) {
    alert( "error" + e );
}

function handler_complete( e ) {
    // The browser has completed the upload, do any clean-up here
}
```

This is mostly copy-and-paste from one of my projects where I do what you're describing (with a couple of changes to tie it in with your code), so you'll see some elements referenced by ID that are in my HTML that you'll have to modify.  But this is essentially what you're looking for to upload files via AJAX.

Comment: There is no `enctype` field in `jQuery.ajax` also `POST` requests aren't cached so setting the cache field is pointless.

Comment: its not wrorking for me. can you please give me the working example using my data? :/

Comment: What does your `$_FILES` array contain in your PHP script?

Comment: $_FILES['file']['name'];
getting empty array

Comment: Without building out the entire process on my end and troubleshooting it, I wouldn't know the specifics. Did you make modifications to the code I posted so that it fit in with your code? For instance, you would either need to change the line `var formData = new FormData( document.getElementById( "form-uploader" ));` to reference your form's ID, or you'd need to assign the ID "form-uploader" to your existing form.

Comment: can you please check this file. this is my complete file.please make it work. http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/497748/test.html